# List app on back of pass in testing and adhoc distrbution mode

Tags: ios, passbook

I'm creating a pass with a companion app, however the companion app is not yet available publicly.

The Passbook Package Format Reference states that the associatedStoreIdentifiers is: 'Optional. A list of iTunes Store item identifiers (also known as Adam IDs) for the associated apps.'

However from my understanding the Adam ID is not the App ID, as if I try using the App ID as the store identifier the pass does not load.

Is it possible to have the app listed on the back of the pass if the app is not yet on the app store?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you will need to wait until you have a valid Adam ID for your App.

You can check [this pass](https://pass.is/SAAfM4) as an example of a pass with a Companion App.

The relevant section of pass.json containing the Adam ID is:

```
"associatedStoreIdentifiers":[584405669]
```

Note that Adam IDs must be sent as integers and grouped into an array, even if there is only one of them. Failure to do this will result in the pass bundle being rejected by Passbook.